# Metrics of the class RankingMetrics, Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, metrics

I use currently the class [RankingMetrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/evaluation/RankingMetrics.html) and can calculate the `precision`. According API of this class, the method for the calculating of `recall` doesn't exist. Can somebody tell me, where I can find the implementation of `recall` for Spark Java?

PS
I have found also some useful [link over all metrics](http://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-releases/spark-1.6.0-rc3-docs/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#ranking-systems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `recall` method exists just with the  `org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics`, `org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MultilabelMetrics` and `org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics`
for the moment.

Check the javadoc for [MulticlassMetrics](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/evaluation/MulticlassMetrics.html), [MultilabelMetrics](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/evaluation/MultilabelMetrics.html) and [BinaryClassificationMetrics](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/evaluation/BinaryClassificationMetrics.html).

[with Spark 1.1+]